# how to show x variables properly on scatterplot in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a R shiny app with scatterplot in it. but the variables on the x axis are long and get mixed into one another. if I tilt them by 45 degree they occupy the plot space and making the plot small. how to fix this?

```
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
projects_selected_date <- data4 %>%
filter(Deployment.Month >= input$date[1] & Deployment.Month <= input$date[2])
q<-ggplot(projects_selected_date, aes_string(x=input$x ,y=input$y),colour= 'red')+ geom_point()
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =45, vjust =0,hjust=0))})
[below image shows the plot with 45 degree]
```